# Qual è la differenza tra "mi dispiace" e "scusa"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

Ciao a tutti, vorrei sapere qual è la differenza tra "mi dispiace" e "scusa". A mio parere "mi dispiace" si usa per dimostrare tristezza verso qualcosa di dispiacevole che è successo a qualcun altro e che non dipende da me. Nel caso di "scusa", invece, si tratta di qualche evento di cui ho responsabilità, in un certo senso "è colpa mia" --> "scusa". "Perdonami" è nell'uso come "Scusa" ma ancora più enfatizzato, credo lo si usi solo in casi estremi.

Voi siete d'accordo? Cosa pensate di questi scenari?

Morte di un parente --> reazione: mi dispiace. 
Ti pesto un piede per sbaglio --> reazione: scusa. 
Ti insulto e mi pento --> reazione: scusa/perdonami.

Comment: Ho trovato questo [sito web](https://podcastitaliano.com/2018/02/03/qual-e-la-differenza-tra-scusa-e-mi-dispiace-intermedio-13/) in cui mi sembra che la differenza sia ben spiegata.

Answer (score 3):

Le tue intuizioni sono corrette.
Dipende tutto dallo scenario, dalla situazione in cui ci si trova.

Puoi trovare in [questo blog](http://www.marilenacremaschini.it/scusa-e-mi-dispiace-non-sono-la-stessa-cosa/) un'interessante analisi delle differenze principali, per cui viene ribadito che "scusa" e "mi dispiace" non sono la stessa cosa:

> **Scusa**
>
> Si chiede “scusa” come cortesia mentre si cerca di farsi largo tra la
> gente e le loro cose, in tal caso è come chiedere il permesso di
> passare e di poter andare oltre, chiedendo alle persone di poter
> spostare le loro cose in modo da creare spazio sufficiente per noi e
> ciò che con noi portiamo. 
> ...
>  Si chiede “scusa” quando si
> accede allo spazio di altre persone, in tale caso si sa di entrare nei
> locali riservati ad altri a cui noi non abbiamo l’accesso se non col
> consenso del titolare o del proprietario. 
> ...
>  “Scusa” in tono
> affermativo è l’imporre una nostra ragione, nulla a che vedere con
> delle scuse vere e proprie ma è il richiamo fermo e deciso su quello
> che l’altro a detto e che dovrebbe riformulare meglio se non vuole
> sentirsi una contestazione od un rimprovero.
>
> **Mi dispiace**
>
> Il dispiacersi per qualcosa presuppone un sentimento di frustrazione,
> di disagio e di dispiacere più profondo e sentito, con la
> consapevolezza di aver realmente fatto del male ad un’altra persona
> che a causa nostra ha sofferto o ha patito un disagio, un torto od un
> danno, di intensità superiore rispetto alla circostanza che avrebbe
> meritato delle semplici scuse. 
> ...
>  Il “mi dispiace” diventa
> una forma di comunicazione, interazione con l’altro e condivisione del
> medesimo sentimento di frustrazione o dolore.

Inoltre sul "mi dispiace" c'è un'interessante [risposta ad un quesito da parte dell'Accademia della Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/dispiace).

Comment: Grazie mille, spiegato benissimo e le situazioni sono proprio chiare! Mi ero dimenticata dello "scusa" con tono affermativo, verissimo! 
Anche se nel caso in cui si sa di entrare nei locali riservati ad altri a cui noi non abbiamo l’accesso se non col consenso del titolare o del proprietario, credo di preferisca "Scusi".

Comment: In quel caso particolare di accesso a spazi altrui, tipo nel caso di una visita ad un conoscente si usa l'espressione "È permesso?" oppure semplicemente "Permesso".